# What is "l’armire"?

Tags: sens

> a mère
>  Une étoile qui leur était apparue, et qui allait devant eux
>   pour leur montrer le chemin. Lorsqu’elle ne bougea plus, et fut sur la
>   crèche, ils surent qu’ils étaient arrivés au terme de leur voyage. Ils
>   entrèrent, adorèrent le Petit Jésus et lui offrirent de l’or, de
>   l’encens et de la myrrhe.
>
> peupeu
>  Maman, est-ce que tu me donneras de **l’armire** ?
>
> la mère
>  Non.
>
> mimi
>  C’est trop grand.

This is from  "La Noël de mes enfants" by Francis Jammes.

What is  "l’armire"?
I can't find the meaning.

I am glad if somebody kindly teach me.

Answer (score 1):

It's ***de la myrrhe*** misspoken.

Peupeu is familiar with this kind of errors as exhibited by this dialog [a little earlier](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_No%C3%ABl_de_mes_enfants):

> la mère
>   Des rois qui ont de beaux habits et qui arrivent avec une **caravane** de chameaux.
>   peupeu
>   Qu’est-ce que c’est qu’une **vacarane** ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I understand it. Hiroshi