# Prétéqueuseuteu

Tags: vocabulaire, prononciation, histoire

Je viens de lire la belle pièce « [La Noël de mes enfants](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_No%C3%ABl_de_mes_enfants) » de [Francis Jammes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Jammes) après l'avoir vue mentionnée dans les [deux](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/what-is-l-armire) [questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/what-does-du-monde-here-mean) récentes qu'a posées un autre utilisateur. Je pense qu'on est sur le point d'avoir démasqué l'identité de tous les mots qui ne figurent point dans les dictionnaires, dont « l'armire, vacarane, menterie ... ».

Mais il en reste un qui n'est représenté dans les résultats Google que dans le texte même de la pièce : « prétéqueseuteu ». Qu'il veut dire « mensonge » ou quelque chose du genre est clair :

> Je vous présente les six enfants du poète. Et leur mère n’est pas morte ! N’allez donc pas colporter, à gauche et à droite, que la femme qui a de nombreux enfants devient tuberculeuse et meurt plus tôt que les femmes qui n’en ont point, ou seulement un ou deux. **C’est une menterie, un « prétéqueuseuteu »**, comme eût prononcé la cuisinière de mon grand-père.

On y voit aussi que c'est du patois vieilli. Or Jammes est né en 1868, donc son grand-père et la cuisinière en question environ 1820-30 probablement, et la famille venait du Pays basque.

J'ai supposé que ce serait un mot composé, la suite de suffixes étant peut-être une transposition phonétique de *-osité* (bien que les genres ne correspondraient pas ...). Cela m'a permis de trouver quelques exemplaires d'une racine provisoire « prétèque » ou « prétéquer » ; mais [les résultats](https://www.google.ca/search?q=pr%C3%A9t%C3%A9qu) pour cette hypothèse s'avèrent être des fautes de ROC pour « prêté que » et ainsi de suite !

Et donc  j'ai révisé ma supposition : comme « prêter qqch. à qn. » peut signifier « attribuer, suggérer », peut-être que « prétéqueseuteu » serait mieux glosé par « rumeur » ... donc « prêter (ce) qu'oses-tu  » ou quelque autre enchêvetrement syntaxique ? Prête-q-osité ?

Ou bien pratique-osité ? (Mais que serait la relation au mensonge ?)

Enfin donc, quelle est sa vraie structure interne ? Quels sont les processus phonétiques qui ont produit les sons qu'on y remarque ? Est-il possible d'identifier la région de cette expression rurale (basque ou autre) ?

Comment: J'imagine que c'est "prétexte".

Comment: Je viens [de lire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/menterie) que menterie est utilisé au Québec, dans l'Hexagone l'emploi de ce mot, bien qu'employé par quelques grands auteurs, fait « rural », même je suppose à l'époque à laquelle Jammes écrivait.

Comment: @Laure: je peux confirmer qu'on utilise encore *menterie* au Canada français dans le langage courant et dans des situations familières. On l'évite, par contre, dans des situations ou un langage soutenu est de mise.

Comment: @Laure, Philippe : Merci ! Oui, j'avais vu des soupçons de « menterie » mais je n'ai pas consulté Wiktionnaire. Très transparent en tout cas. Intéressant qu'il s'emploie toujours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ce n'est pas du patois, c'est vraiment comme dit le texte (« comme eût prononcé la cuisinière de mon grand-père ») un élément de prononciation.

Les enfants qui ne savent pas encore bien parler, et certainement les personnes qui ne savent pas lire, (et il est fort possible que ce soit le cas de la cuisinière en question), ont du mal à prononcer certains groupes de consonnes comme [ks] et *prétexte* est souvent prononcé *prétesque*. Cependant il ne s'agit pas ici de la déformation classique /pʁetɛsk/ → /pʁetɛkst/ mais de l'insertion du son /ə/ (plus vraisemblablement que /ø/), après les consonnes qu'elle a du mal à prononcer /pʁetek**ə**s**ə**t**ə**/.
Cet ajout correspond à un trait classique du français méridional qui transforme le e muet en schwa.

La suite est il me semble évidente, il suffit de passer de [mensonge](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mensonge) à [prétexte](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pr%C3%A9texte).

Comment: Oh, zut ! Voici mon erreur : j'ai omis de considérer cette acception littérale de « prononcer », y entendant au lieu tout simplement « s'exprimer » (en raison du chevauchement avec « énoncer ») ! But the chance to learn about the insertion and "un-reduction" of those schwas is much appreciated. Merci d'avoir clarifié le téqueuseuteu. :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Le schwa est un sujet qui inspire les linguistes. Voir la première phrase (« Choisir le schwa comme objet d’étude, c’est d’emblée se situer dans une filiation de travaux très nombreux, trop nombreux pour certains,... ») de la conférence [*À la recherche du schwa : données, méthodes et théories*](https://www.shs-conferences.org/articles/shsconf/abs/2014/05/shsconf_cmlf14_01396/shsconf_cmlf14_01396.html) donnée par le linguiste Jacques Durand au  Congrès Mondial de Linguistique Française en 2014.

Comment: Peut-être que menterie est à mensonge ce que prétexte est à supercherie...